# Element.matches selector limitations

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) with a complex selector but I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': ':not(.myContainer *)' is not a valid selector.
```

```js
var myMatchedElement = document.getElementById('iShould');
console.log(myMatchedElement.matches(':not(.myContainer *)'));

var myNotMatchedElement = document.getElementById('iShouldNot');
console.log(myNotMatchedElement.matches(':not(.myContainer *)'));
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="iShould">I should match the selector</div>
  <div class="myContainer">
    <span id="iShouldNot">I should not</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version of the selector, but basically I need the ":not(.class childs)" and using Element.matches.

Comment: `:not()` only accepts simple selectors, `.myContainer *` is a complex selector. Even CSS wouldn't accept your rule.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that in another answer... I was confused because I was using that selector in JQuery

Comment: Yes jQuery :not is not the w3c one (it was made before, and accepts more complex selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) still only accepts [*simple selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn), `.myContainer *` is a [*complex selector*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#complex) and not a *simple selector*.

Even CSS wouldn't accept your rule.

```css
:not(.myContainer *) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="iShould">I should match the selector</div>
  <div class="myContainer">
    <span id="iShouldNot">I should not</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#negation) now extend the `not()` function to accept a *list of complex selectors*, but only Safari has implemented it yet.